# Remove dynamic elements that were created after the dom was loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of fieldset elements that are hidden when all of the list items inside them are not visible. The problem is I want to actually remove the field sets after they slide up and are hidden but I'm having trouble getting that to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on("click", ".readBtn", function (e) {
        var chapterID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[A-Za-z_]+/g, '');

        $('#chapter_'+chapterid).slideUp(function () {
          if (!$(this).is(":visible") 
             && !$(this).siblings("li").is(":visible")) {
            // Hide `fieldset`
            var parent = $(this).closest("fieldset");
            parent.slideUp();
            parent.remove();
          }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
button.readBtn {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="story">
    <legend>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Title 1
        </a>
    </legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_9">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_9">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="story">
    <legend>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Title 2
        </a>
    </legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_10">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_10">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_12">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_12">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I've read that you can't use the jquery.click call in order to remove an element that was created after page load, so that's why I went with using the on call. But I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Suggest you start over. `e` argument in event handler is the event object but you are using as jQuery object. `this` inside the handler is the button that is clicked. Parts of your code make no sense which is why I suggest starting over and traverse from `$(this)`

Comment: @charlietfl so use $(this) instead of the event e?

Comment: Yes, you can also access element as property of `event` but using `this` is the most common way

Comment: Try substituting `$('#chapter_'+chapterid).slideUp()` (see lowercase **id**) to `$('#chapter_'+chapterID).slideUp()`

Comment: >>ReferenceError: chapterid is not defined.   Should be ChapterID in this: $('#chapter_'+chapterid).slideUp(function ()

Comment: @guest271314 that certainly was an issue, but for some reason it is removing the fieldset even though it still contains another visible li child.

Comment: I don't see that behavior happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/jplato/zp91wzc0/  Is this not the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: @JPlato your example does exactly what it is supposed to and the only difference I can see is using this instead of e.target. Why would that be?

Comment: Not exactly sure why it works with this, but the problem with using sibling() as you were is that the "li" you're looking for is not a sibling of e.currentTarget.  e.currentTarget is the button, and it's sibling is the anchor tag that precedes it.  You want the sibling of the parent: $(e.currentTarget).parent().sibling("li:visible").  You also don't want to do a boolean evaluation of that, because jQuery will always return an array, which will evaluate to true even if it's empty.  So, you want to do something lie this: if($(e.currentTarget).parent().sibling("...").length > 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.readBtn').click(function () {
        var chapterID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[A-Za-z_]+/g, '');

        $('#chapter_'+chapterID).slideUp(function() {
          if (!$(this).is(":visible") 
             && !$(this).siblings("li").is(":visible")) {
            // hide `fieldset`
            // remove `fieldset` if all `li` siblings _not_ visible ,
            // at `.hide()` `complete` callback
            $(this).closest("fieldset").hide(function() {
              $(this).remove()
            })
          }
        });

    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.readBtn').click(function () {
    var chapterID = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[A-Za-z_]+/g, '');

    $('#chapter_'+chapterID).slideUp(function() {
      if (!$(this).is(":visible") 
         && !$(this).siblings("li").is(":visible")) {
        // hide `fieldset`
        $(this).closest("fieldset").hide(function() {
          $(this).remove()
        })
      }
    });

});
})
```

```css
button.readBtn {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="story">
    <legend>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Title 1
        </a>
    </legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_9">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_9">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="story">
    <legend>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            Title 2
        </a>
    </legend>
    <ul>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_10">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_10">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="chapter" id="chapter_12">
            <a  href="#" target="_blank">
                Chapter Title
            </a>
            <button class="readBtn" id="readBtn_12">
                Mark as Read
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks guest! I'm glad this comes back the simpler click event. I also didn't think to put the remove call into the hide function. I really like how the hide function finishes first.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on("click", ".readBtn", function (e) {
        liEl = $(e.currentTarget).parent();
        var chapterID = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id').split('_').pop();

        $('#chapter_'+chapterID).slideUp(function () {
          if (!liEl.is(":visible") 
             && !liEl.siblings(":visible").length > 0) {
            // Hide `fieldset`
            var parent = liEl.closest("fieldset");
            parent.slideUp();
            parent.remove();
          }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jplato/zp91wzc0/1/